# Where is .NET "Isolated Storage" stored?

Tags: .net, isolatedstorage

Where would the physical files be?

Comment: I think it depends on which technology you are using. The location is different for WinRT apps, Silverlight app etc. Also it depends on OS, Roming profiles etc.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It depends on the OS and whether or not roaming user profiles are enabled.

For example, on XP, with non-roaming profiles, the location is

```
<SYSTEMDRIVE>\Documents and Settings\<user>\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\IsolatedStorage
```

On Vista with roaming profile storage,

```
<SYSTEMDRIVE>\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\IsolatedStorage
```

See an [Introduction to Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy.aspx) for more info.

Comment: in case of ASP.NET applications it is in ` \Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\ `

Comment: in my case on 7 it was `%userprofile%\AppData\LocalLow\Microsoft\Silverlight\is`

Answer (score 17):

`%LocalAppData%\IsolatedStorage` / `%AppData%\IsolatedStorage.`

I didn't find them under "Microsoft"

Comment: same here, for a winforms app I was developing in Windows 8, I found it under %LocalAppData%\IsolatedStorage

Comment: I rejected the edit because it was an ungrammatical typo; feel free to make it again

Answer (score 9):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + 
    "\\IsolatedStorage"
    );
```

Answer (score 4):

On my XP workstation I found it under c:\Documents and Settings\\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Silverlight\is\XXXXXXXXXXXXX
Where xxxxxxxx appears to be a random directory name.  (under that if you wander around enough you should find the store for your particular app...)

Answer (score 4):

I've also seen it under `%ProgramData%\IsolatedStorage` (so often C:\ProgramData\IsolatedStorage).

This particular case was a Windows Server 2008 with IIS site-related data.

Comment: This is where it was on Windows 10 for my ClickOnce WPF application.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Windows 8.1. On my PC its in `C:\Users\mangesh\AppData\LocalLow\Microsoft\Silverlight\<followed by some random folder names>`

In 'Silverlight' folder there are many random folders. You should find your files in one of these folders.

Answer (score 3):

Location differs per `IsolationStorage` scope

```
Local user     [LocalApplicationData]\IsolatedStorage
Roaming user   [ApplicationData]\IsolatedStorage
Machine        [CommonApplicationData]\IsolatedStorage
```

The folders can be retrieved by `Environment.GetFolderPath` method.

Windows 2016 has it like this

```
Local user     C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\IsolatedStorage
Roaming user   C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\IsolatedStorage
Machine        C:\ProgramData\IsolatedStorage
```

More details can be found [here](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/IsolatedStorage.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

When accessed/created by a system account, I found the folder here:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\IsolatedStorage
```