# What is the Isolated Storage Location in Windows 7 and 8?

Tags: .net, silverlight, c#-4.0, isolatedstorage, xap

I want to store a file in my Windows 8 or Windows 7 Isolated Storage location.?
Knowing the location, i want to place some files in the location. 
So, how to get the location of the isolated storage file loction..?

```
 using(IsolatedStorageFile isoPath=IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
}
```

What is the location we get on IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()...?

Comment: Possible Duplicate... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275536/where-is-net-isolated-storage-stored

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find complete solution for that. Just copy/past code to a new WPF Application project.

Do not forget some assembly references i.e.

> System.Web.Extention
>
> System.Web.Script.Serialization
>
> System.IO.IsolatedStorage;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MySettings settings = MySettings.Read(true);
            Debug.WriteLine("Current value of 'myInteger': " + settings.myInteger);
            Debug.WriteLine("Incrementing 'myInteger'...");
            settings.myInteger++;
            Debug.WriteLine("Saving settings...");
            settings.Save(true);
            Debug.WriteLine("Done.");

        }

        private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MySettings settings = MySettings.Read(true);
            Debug.WriteLine("Current value of 'myInteger': " + settings.myInteger);
            Debug.WriteLine("Incrementing 'myInteger'...");
            settings.myInteger++;
            settings.myString = "new S1";
            Debug.WriteLine("Saving settings...");
            settings.Save(true);
            Debug.WriteLine("Done.");

            lbl1.Content = settings.myString;
        }
    }

    class MySettings : AppSettings<MySettings>
    {
        public string myString = "Hello World";
        public int myInteger = 1;
    }

    public class AppSettings<T> where T : new()
    {
        private const string DEFAULT_FILENAME = "Settings";


        private static string GetSettingFileName
        {
            get
            {
                var exeName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
                var fullFileName = string.Format("{0}_{1}.json", exeName, DEFAULT_FILENAME);
                return fullFileName;
            }
        }

        public void Save(bool isIsolatedStrorage)
        {
            if (isIsolatedStrorage)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(GetSettingFileName, FileMode.Create, IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForAssembly()))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
                        {
                            writer.Write((new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(this));
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
            else // We will create settings file in the same directory. All users will can access to it. Settings are non user independed.
            {
                File.WriteAllText(GetSettingFileName, (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(this));
            }
        }

        public static void Save(T pSettings, bool isIsolatedStrorage)
        {
            if (isIsolatedStrorage)
            {
                try
                {

                    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(GetSettingFileName, FileMode.Create, IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForAssembly()))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
                        {
                            writer.Write((new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(pSettings));
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
            else // We will create settings file in the same directory. All users will can access to it. Settings are non user independed.
            {
                File.WriteAllText(GetSettingFileName, (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(pSettings));
            }
        }

        public static T Read(bool isIsolatedStrorage)
        {
            T t = new T();
            if (isIsolatedStrorage)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(GetSettingFileName, FileMode.Open, IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForAssembly()))
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        t = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<T>(reader.ReadToEnd());
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
            }
            else // We will create settings file in the same directory. All users will can access to it. Settings are non user independed.
            {
                if (File.Exists(GetSettingFileName))
                    t = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<T>(File.ReadAllText(GetSettingFileName));
            }

            return t;
        }
    }
}
```

You can find settings file created by path like

> C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\IsolatedStorage\cogrxuh4.gma\140esil0.t05\Url.bejzwgwbgheugcdwci5jbycjpt0p5rke\AssemFiles

Perhaps this part `"cogrxuh4.gma\140esil0.t05\Url.bejzwgwbgheugcdwci5jbycjpt0p5rke"` will be different in your case.

Also using this class you can keep all settings locally at the same directory where you have **EXE** file.

ANd finally you will need define some `AppConfigurationManager` class where you can implement all job asynchronously.